# Get all information for products by categories - SQL?

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sql-order-by, categories

Since this is the best page I've ever found in case of question like this, I wanna ask this here. I'm a little bit confused here. I'm a beginner in SQL statements, so I need your help, please. I have three tables:

- product
- product_category
- product_to_category

I show you the exported SQL file, so you may get this:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `productID` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `productPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `productQuantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `product` (`productID`, `productTitle`, `productDescription`, `productPrice`, `productQuantity`) VALUES
(1, 'Chlor 5L', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \r\n\r\nDuis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. \r\n\r\nUt wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \r\n\r\nNam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \r\n\r\nDuis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. ', 14.95, 50),
(2, 'Chlor 15L', 'Mit diesem Kanister kommen Sie etwa 27.000 Liter aus.', 50, 13),
(3, 'Chlor 20L', 'Mit diesem Kanister kommen Sie etwa 37.000 Liter aus.', 60, 2),
(4, 'Chlor 25L', 'Mit diesem Kanister kommen Sie etwa 47.000 Liter aus.', 79, 11),
(5, 'Kieselgur 50kg', 'Eine menge Kieselgur zum säubern.', 69.99, 9);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_category` (
  `categoryID` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categoryDescription` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `product_category` (`categoryID`, `categoryName`, `categoryDescription`) VALUES
(1, 'Schwimmbecken', 'Hier finden Sie alle Produkte rund um das Thema Schwimmbecken.'),
(2, 'Whirlpool', 'Hier finden Sie alle Produkte rund um das Thema Whirlpools.'),
(3, 'Sauna', 'Hier finden Sie alle Produkte rund um das Thema Sauna.'),
(4, 'Infrarot', 'Hier finden Sie alle Produkte rund um das Thema Infrarotkabinen.');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_to_category` (
  `categoryID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `productID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `productAddedTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryID`,`productID`),
  KEY `productID` (`productID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `product_to_category` (`categoryID`, `productID`, `productAddedTime`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2011-11-27 13:57:12'),
(1, 2, '2011-11-27 13:57:12'),
(1, 3, '2011-11-27 13:57:12'),
(1, 4, '2011-11-27 13:57:12'),
(1, 4, '2011-11-27 13:57:12'),
(2, 1, '2011-11-27 13:57:12');

ALTER TABLE `product_to_category`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_to_category_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `product_category` (`categoryID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `product_to_category_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) REFERENCES `product` (`productID`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

So, what I wanna do is: I want to get all information of ALL products. I want to group them on ONE page by there categories. In addition I wanna show the number of products in each category. I do not know, how to do this. I get the right number of products per category with this statement, but just on product. But I want alle information on products of ALL products in ALL categories, hopefully I stated my point, otherwise you may ask again. I try to explain it.

```
SELECT COUNT(ptc.productID) AS productCount, pc.categoryName, p.productTitle, p.productPrice 
FROM product_category pc
JOIN product_to_category ptc ON pc.categoryID = ptc.categoryID
JOIN product p ON ptc.productID = p.productID
GROUP BY pc.categoryName
```

I hope you have an answer for me...

Want I wanna do is a overview like this:

```
Schwimmbecken (5 products)    
 - Chlor 5L (14.95)
 - Chlor 15L (50.00)
 - Chlor....

Whirlpool (1 product)  
 - Chlor 5L (14.95)
```

Hope this was enough to show ya...

Comment: to make it clearer please show some sample data and wanted result...

Comment: I hope you can deal with my last edit.

Comment: the result you show and the sample data you provied don't match - for example: where does 14.50 come from ? the data contains only 14.95 ?

Comment: You're right. The example is wrong, there sould be the 14.95 of course.

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close but I would 'start' with either product or category.
I would start with product, link to product_category and then to catergory e.g. something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.productID) AS productCount, c.categoryName, p.productTitle, p.productPrice 
FROM product p 
JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.categoryID = p.productID
JOIN category c ON ptc.catgeory_id = c.categoryID 
ORDER BY c.categoryName
```

Start with this, examine the results and then add grouping as appropriate.

Comment: I started that way, but this gives me same result... I get the right number of products in the category, but just ONE procut...

Comment: Did you try grouping? Say pc.category_id ?

Comment: Now I see your output I can see you probably want to have an inner select, e.g. `select col1, col2, col3`, (select fields from tbl, join to an existing table alias), `col4, col5` style for the 'detail' rows.

Answer (score 1):

use (corrected version)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
c.categoryName || '(' || c.cnt || ' products)' title,
x.productTitle || '(' || x.productPrice || ')' productinfo
FROM
(
select 
pc.categoryid, 
pc.categoryName, 
count(distinct p2c.productID) cnt 
from product_category pc 
INNER JOIN product_to_category p2c ON p2c.categoryid = pc.categoryid
group by pc.categoryid, pc.categoryName
) c
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
ptc.categoryid, 
p.productTitle, 
p.productPrice
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON p.productID = ptc.productID
) x ON x.categoryid = c.categoryid
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

This will give what you ask for except for one thing - the `title` will be repeated as often as there are products in the respective category... that part can't be handled via SQL itself, you will have to handle it in your code...

**EDIT - as per comments:**

The above select makes inner join between two SELECTs... first gets one row per category plus the count of products in that category... second gets all products per category... these are joined via the categoryid...

Just tried it with your sample data and got the following result:

```
TITLE                   PRODUCTINFO

Schwimmbecken(4 products)   Chlor 15L(50)
Schwimmbecken(4 products)   Chlor 20L(60)
Schwimmbecken(4 products)   Chlor 25L(79)
Schwimmbecken(4 products)   Chlor 5L(14,95)
Whirlpool(1 products)       Chlor 5L(14,95)
```

BTW: your sample data seems off... you have two times `productId` 4 in `categoryID` 1 while `productID` 5 is not used anywhere...

Comment: Wow, this looks scary... I tested this on my phpMyAdmin platform. This shows just one line as a result. The productCount is 5, categoryName = Schwimmbecken, productTitle = Chlor 5L and productPrice = 14.95 - but I want these information for ALL products in this category...

Comment: Well, this is worse. It shows just to colums title and productinfo, just one row and both values are 1. Nothing else. Maybe you explain something about your query. I tried to understand it, but I failed. Mayby after your explanation I can deal with it myself. But I already thank ya for ya engangement!

Comment: @ccq21 For explanation see my EDIT... I just tried it here (on an Oracle DB) and works just fine... added the result to my answer... if that fails in your environment then the data is not as you showed in your question...

Comment: My data is correct. One product may match two categories at once. Thats why the primary key are both attributes. On the other site a product does not need to match a category at all. I understand your query now... I guess... But I do not see, why there is this mistake. Here is a screenshot, of what a accomplish on that...

http://i40.tinypic.com/6rht81.jpg

Comment: @ccq21 please look exactly at the data you provided - you have productID 4 twice in category 1, which violates the primary key!

Comment: @ccq21 the screenshot does not contain the complete query... AND it just says that there are no results - which can only happen if your real data and the sample data you provided do not match!

Comment: There is the complete query. It is in a scrollbar, which is not on the screen. I have no idea, why it is not matching. The provided .sql file is exactly, what I have in my db...

Comment: @ccq21 I can only tell you that it works fine on Oracle... and that the provided sample data violates your primary key definition since the same combination of product and category is twice in the same table...